# How to change a file name based on the directory it is in for packaging

Tags: deployment, gradle

I have the following gradle task:

```
task copyToDeployDir(dependsOn: preDeploy) << {
  copy {
    from codeDir
    into deployDir
  }
}
```

This works great for copying from my code dir (usually `main` or `src`) into a deployment directory. However, I want to rename a few of these files. Specifically, since I'm using CodeIgniter, I want to rename a couple of the controllers to start with an "install" controller.

Ideally, what I want is to copy over all of the files into deployDir, except any files that are in `codeDir/application/controllers`, I want to rename to have a suffix of `.dist`.

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this. I previously tried the renaming stuff in Working with Files in the gradle documentation, but it doesn't seem to work with gradle 2.2.

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Opal. I'll look into it today, I got sidetracked on other things. It looks like it will, and as soon as I try it, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
task copyToDeployDir(dependsOn: preDeploy, type: Copy) << {
  from(codeDir) {
     exclude '**/application/controllers/*'
  }

  from(codeDir) {
     include '**/application/controllers/*'
     rename {
        "${it}.suffix"
     }
  }
  into deployDir
}
```